# Unable to compare two integer values in Arduino Mega

Tags: serial, arduino-mega, data-type

I wrote Arduino code (code is given at the end) to compare two integer values. The steps I took was:

1. Give input to DC motor to rotate it using serial port. Input was: `G254`
2. Then I store it in `XX` string and using `XX.remove(0,1);` I removed `G` from `G254`. `XX` now become `254`
3. Then I used `Serial1.println("P");` to get position of motor after rotation. I stored this value in `ZZ` string using `String  ZZ = Serial1.readString();`. `ZZ` will be `P254`.
4. And using `XX.remove(0,1);` I removed `P` from `P254`. `ZZ` now become `254`.
5. Now, I convert both `XX` and `ZZ` into integer from string using  `XX.toInt(); ZZ.toInt();` .
6. After that, I compare both values using:

> ```
> if (XX == ZZ)
> {
>     Serial.println("BOTH ARE EQUAL");
> }
> else 
> {
>     Serial.println("BOTH ARE NOT EQUAL");
> }
> ```

But it shows `BOTH ARE NOT EQUAL` which is not true. I want to know where I'm making a mistake?

Code I used:

```
void setup() {
    // put your setup code here, to run once:
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial1.begin(9600);

    pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
    // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
    if (Serial.available() > 0)
    {
        Serial1.println(Serial.readString());

        String  XX = Serial1.readString();
        XX.remove(0,1);

        Serial1.println("P");

        String  ZZ = Serial1.readString();
        ZZ.remove(0,1);

        XX.toInt();
        ZZ.toInt();
        Serial.println(ZZ);
        Serial.println(XX);
        Serial.println(typeof(XX));

        if (XX == ZZ)
        {
            Serial.println("BOTH ARE EQUAL");
        }
        else 
        {
             Serial.println("BOTH ARE NOT EQUAL");
        }
    }    
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: A question will get downvotes if question shows no effort. *Fine*. But I tried hard and do above coding by myself. I need to add *int x* (Thanks @Michel) in my code which I don't know and that's why I put my question here. I think this question should not be downvoted  on the basis of efforts because I try to find out a solution from other sources but cann't and at last, I put my query here. I loose my points unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
 int x = XX.toInt()
```

Without the int x = part, the string is converted and the result (the integer) is not used.

Also comparing strings should be done with the strcmp function. The problem is that if you compare two strings, you compare the pointers to those strings and two strings can have equal texts but (probably) not equal addresses.

Comment: Might need to add that XX.toInt() returns the value of the string after converting to a number. It does not convert the string (internally) to a number. The string is still a string. Also it is possible to compare the strings directly to be equal.

Comment: @MikaelPatel. String comparison is alphabetic, not numeric.

Comment: @LookAlterno True but equal is equal even for strings - isn't it :) https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StringComparisonOperators

Comment: @MikaelPatel There are people that learn JavaScript or PHP as a first language; unaware of the differences.

Comment: Thanks for all comments, I updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code.

First, never assume that Serial.readString() will returns you a complete String; it can time out and return nothing, or return just an incomplete value.

`Serial.available() > 0` doesn't imply that the reading is complete ...

Second, Serial.readString() returns everything, include the possible \r\n at the end of the string.

Here is a little sketch that shows a `toInt` implementation fit for you case. Run this sketch to see how it works.

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while(!Serial);
}

void loop() {
  String x = Serial.readString();
  Serial.print(x); Serial.print("=");
  Serial.println(myToInt(x));
}

int myToInt(String x) {
  char* p = x.c_str();
  int val = 0;

  while(*p != 0 && !isdigit(*p)) {
    p++;
  }

  while (*p != 0 && isdigit(*p)) {
    val = val * 10 + (*p - '0');
    p++;
  }
  return val;
}
```